# How is the object std::cout constructed/instantiated

Tags: c++

So std::cout is an object. My doubt is how/where is it constructed/instantiated.

Thanks.

Comment: In the library somewhere that you don't have easy access to. Remember that you're not guaranteed anything about *how* it's constructed, just that it is and what it'll do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's constructed by `ios_base::Init`. First time that object is created, `cout` and friends are created. If the last object is destroyed, `cout` and friends are flushed (calling `.flush()`).

In C++0x it will be guaranteed that if you include `<iostream>`, and use of `cout` and friends after the `#include` will use constructed `cout` and friends objects. In C++03, it is said that

> The objects are constructed, and the associations are established at some time prior to or during first time an object of class `ios_base::Init` is constructed, and in any case before the body of main begins execution.