# How std::cout works

Tags: c++, cout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between cout<<cout and cout<<&cout in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489069/whats-the-difference-between-coutcout-and-coutcout-in-c)

I accidentally found:

```
cout << cout;
```

The output is some address. What does this address mean, and why is it shown?
I am looking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508857/how-does-cout-actually-work).

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489069/whats-the-difference-between-coutcout-and-coutcout-in-c

Comment: Thanks Charles Bailey for the link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `ostream` overload `operator void*()`, and that's the closes match for the call to `operator <<`, the result of the cast `(void*)cout` is printed. Which in your case is that address. Remember that `cout` is an object.

Basically the call translates to:

```
cout.operator<<((void*)cout);
```

Comment: why c++ used << operator? calls a function without parenthesis?

Comment: @Pooya in C++ you can overload operators for convenience in typing. Research the subject, too much to explain in a comment.

Comment: yes, I know the operator overloading, but you use << for lift shifting according to right operand

Comment: @Pooya, While in C, it was strictly used for that, in C++, it became overloaded for streams like the input and output streams. It doesn't really have anything to do with bit shifting any more when it's used like that. You can make `operator+` do subtraction, but the difference is that here, they've drilled it in to make sense in the context, whereas my example is absurd.

Comment: yes, I found that, in c++ ostream and istream has override << and >> as operator for input and output

Answer (score 2):

`cout` is an `ostream` object that have an overloaded [insertion(`<<`) operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/). If we look at the constructor of the `ostream` class, there is an argument to be passed which is a pointer to `streambuf` object. `streambuf` objects are normally associated with a character sequence which they use to read and write data. For a console application there will be such a character buffer associated with the standard output which *might* be used internally in case of cout. It is said in the documentation that we are not expected to directly instantiate the `ostream` object but use any of the derived classes, `ofstream` or `ostringstream` diverting attention from stdout.

Regarding the address getting printed, I think Luchian Grigore is right.

This question will get you an idea on how and where the `cout` object is instantiated: [How is the object std::cout constructed/instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457795/how-is-the-object-stdcout-constructed-instantiated)